# Interface inheritance - How to not break Liskov's Substitution Principle and the Single Responsibility Pattern?

Tags: c#, design-patterns, inheritance, liskov-substitution-principle

I have a generic repository pattern, and I'm now seeing that I need a custom method for one specific implementation of this pattern, let's call the implementation CustomerRepository and the method GetNextAvailableCustomerNumber. I have a few ideas but they're not conforming to the SOLID principles of object-oriented design.

I first considered to make a custom repository pattern (ICustomerRepository) for that implementation, but that is not really very feasible. Experience tells me that there has to be some other way which I have not yet considered or even know about at the present time. Besides, I don't think that inventing a new repository interface for every bump in the road should be done so lightly.

I then considered making ICustomerRepository inherit IRepository<Customer> and just add the method signature for GetNextAvailableCustomer, but that goes very much against Liskov's Substitution Principle and I believe it also goes ever so slightly against the Single Responsibility Pattern. I would still be able to implement a customer repository based on IRepository, even though I'd only want to use ICustomerRepository. I would end up with two alternatives and it would no longer be obvious which interface the client should be implementing. I would in this case wish for it only to be possible to implement ICustomerRepository, and not IRepository<Customer>

What would be the proper way to go about this? Is interface inheritance really the way to go, or is there any other preferred method of approach which ideally would conform to LSP?

This is my generic repository interface:

```
public interface IRepository<T>
    where T : IEntity
{
    T GetById(int id);

    IList<T> GetAll();

    IEnumerable<T> Query(Func<T, bool> filter);

    int Add(T entity);

    void Remove(T entity);

    void Update(T entity);
}
```

Comment: Why do you think that ICustomerRepository inhereting form IRepository goes against Liskov's Substitution principle?

Comment: "Subtypes must be substitutable for their base types." If you add a new method GetNextAvailableCustomer to ICustomerRepository, it will still be substitutable by IRepository.

Comment: Because an implementation of ICustomerRepository would not be substituable for IRepository<Customer>, as that implementation would have the GetNextAvailableCustomerNumber-method. An implementation of IRepository<Customer> would not have that.

Comment: @Maritim That is not what is meant by liskovs. "objects in a program should be replaceable with instances of their subtypes without altering the correctness of that program"

Comment: ICustomerRepository inherits IRepository and not the other way.

Comment: So basically the part about LSP boils down to an overly strict interpreation on my part. Thank you so much for clarifying!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are actually not breaking Liskov's Substitution Principle. Liskov's says

> objects in a program should be replaceable with instances of their
>   subtypes without altering the correctness of that program

In your case you can. With your interpretation of Liskov almost no inheritance and extensions of classes will be allowed.

I think that a ICustomerRepository that "inherents" from IRepository would be just fine. I can still replace ICustomerRepository everywhere where I would use IRepostory (given ICustomerRepository:IRepostory)

Liskov guards against unexpected behavior of subclasses. The most used (although not necessarily the beste) example seems to be the example where a square inherets from a rectangle. Here we have a SetWidth method that is overridden by Square, but Square also sets the height since it is a square. The original methods definition is therefore changed in the subclass and therefore violates the principle.

Comment: That is a great relief for sure. Is it possible to deny implementation of IRepository<Customer> except by means of implementing ICustomerRepository?

Comment: Not use what you mean with " Is it possible to deny implementation of IRepository<Customer>"?

Answer (score 1):

You will not break the LSP.

`Subtypes must be substitutable for their base types.` (LSP from Agile.Principles.Patterns.and Practices.In.C#[Robert.C.Martin] book)

If you add a new method GetNextAvailableCustomer to ICustomerRepository, it will still be substitutable by IRepository.

Here is a good article for the repository pattern [Entity Framework, Repository and Specification Pattern](http://huyrua.wordpress.com/2010/07/13/entity-framework-4-poco-repository-and-specification-pattern/)

[source code for different .net versions](https://code.google.com/p/ef4prs/downloads/list)

Answer (score 1):

Liskov did not mean to extinguish any means to extend a program. The substitution principle is about correctness of the program when you replace a basetype by a subtype.

It is perfectly valid to add additional methods to the subtypes though: Any place where a base type is expected does *not* know of nor use the additional methods. If you replace the implementation used in those places by a subclass, those places in your code will still work perfectly.

An example of breaking the LSP would be if you create an implementation that throws an exception when you call "Query", or where the "Remove" method adds an element and the "add" method removes an element.

As far as I know creating a `ICustomerRepository` which inherits from `IRepository<Customer>` and adds customer specific methods is exactly how the repository pattern was meant.